# Calculating optimal division for each element in array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

Suppose I have array of positive integers, each standing for a length of a rod, e.g.:

```
[26, 103, 59]
```

I want to find some positive integer size into which I will cut each of these rods. I will be penalized by the total number of cuts I make and by the sum of the remainders.

---

**Example**

For example, if I cut the rods whose lengths are as above, into pieces of length 6, I will get:

- rod one (length 26): 4 pieces + remainder 2
- rod two (length 103): 17 pieces + remainder 1
- rod three (length 59): 9 pieces + remainder 5

The penalties are

- 4 + 17 + 9 = 30 cuts
- 2 + 1 + 5 = 8 remainder

---

I'd like an algorithm taking as inputs:

- an array of rod lengths
- a cut-penalty cost
- a remainder-penalty cost

and outputting the optimal cut size.

Comment: So what's your code? And where did you get stuck?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/juniper-hackathon/challenges/metals

This is the problem.

And I got stuck in finding optimum length for rod

Comment: and do you have any initial idea for your algorithm?

Comment: First case I tried with taking minimum value out of array, and use that as a optimum length. This algo will fail if there is very small number and others are very large numbers. Total cut cost will be much higher in that case.

And in other case If I consider taking average of sum of the array, that will be again pretty bad solution.

Comment: All numbers in the constraints are small enough, so that you could just brute force the solution…

Comment: maximum of a rod length is 10000 and maximum of number of rods is 50 so brute force with O(n2) is acceptable. Try to cut from length of 1 to the maximum length and evaluate profit for each case, choose the greatest one.

Comment: As it stands, the question is completely unclear without reading the full problem statement. You should at least specify what value you want to maximize.

Comment: Two things specifies what I want:
1: "So I can throw little bit of remaining final cut pieces." (we don't want to waste the rods)
2: "I have cost of cut to consider. I want to find optimum length of rod to cut."

Answer (score 0):

It is a brute force solution just try it.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        long c=s.nextLong();
        long pr=s.nextLong();
        long l=s.nextLong();
        long[] array=new long[(int)l];
        long max=0;
        for(int x=0;x<l;x++){
             array[x]=s.nextLong();
             if(max<array[x])
                  max=array[x];
        }
        long ans=0;
        for(int p=1;p<=max;p++){
            long sum=0;
            long cut=0;
            for(int q=0;q<l;q++){
                sum+=(array[q]/p);
                if(array[q]%p==0){
                cut+=(array[q]/p)-1;
                }else{
                    cut+=(array[q]/p);
                }

            }
            long cost=sum*p*pr-cut*c;
            if(cost>ans)
                 ans=cost;

        }
        System.out.println(ans);   

    }
}
```

Comment: `for(int p=1;p<max;p++){` : What if `max` gives the most optimized answer? It should be `p<=max`. The snippet to calculate profit also wrong because sometime num_of_cut is not equal to num_of_rod. For example, we need only `1` cut for one 4-rod to have `2` 2-rod.

Comment: Yes that was wrong but now i have edited,Please check it out & tell me if i am wrong & thanks for pointing out mistake

Comment: Consider adding a paragraph where you explain the idea behind the code.

Comment: @nikhiljain: It's better now. You can use `cut += (array[q] - 1) / p;` instead of `if` statement. Both have same result.

Comment: @Sandesh Can you please submit the code on hackerrank.com & tell me what is the score.